# OpenGL Polygon Rendering inconsistency

Tags: opengl, rendering, polygon

I am using opengl simple commands for demonstration purpose in my project. Well, my project is similar to mesh a rectangle region into a set of small convex polygons. First, I tried to render the rectangle region in unfilled mode using the following code.

```
void draw_boundary_unfilled(const double line_width,const double red, const double      green, const double blue) const
    {
        glLineWidth(line_width);
        glColor3d(red,green,blue);

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT,GL_LINE);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < Polygon::size(); ++i)
        {
            const Point& pi = Polygon::vertex(i);
            glVertex2f(pi.x(), pi.y());
        }
        glEnd();
}
```

Note: the "Polygon" is a container in which I stored the vertices of either the rectangle or convex polygons.

It worked well with the rectangle region. After I did the mesh thing, I tried to use the same code for rendering each small convex polygons within the rectangle. It showed me, however, a whole filled rectangle region in which I had no way to tell edges of each convex polygon . It seemed to be an inconsistency. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Maybe the vertex order is reversed so you render the backfaces. And you haven't specified a render mode for back faces.

Comment: Do you think I can test the orientation of each convex polygon and decide whether to render back faces or front faces accordingly?

Comment: If I wanna specify both front and back faces mode to be GL_LINE, how can I do so?

Comment: I just tried "glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);" It worked as I need. Thanks a lot, Nico.